# Lightswitch DateTimePicker renders incorrectly on another server

Tags: datetimepicker, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a Lightswitch DateTimePicker which works fine on my development machine.

When running from an external server the following screen is displayed :

[image]

The day dropdown shows "/msls/dateTimePicker_dayNumberAndDayPattern" for all days in the dropdown.

Cannot see any missing JS files from the installation.

Comment: It does look like something (perhaps in the .NET runtimes) hasn't been installed. What version of .NET is on your machine and what version is on the server?

Comment: Both have .NET 4.5 installed.

Comment: It looks like the server is unable to read/load the msls...resjson file which has the key=value pair mappings.
Therefore have decided to modify the msls-2.5.1.js file to hardcode the values required and display day numbers instead. Seems to work ok.